# Assign a Row of Floats to a 2-D Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to assign floats to a 2-D numpy array. The 2-D array originally consists of integers. After my assignment, the row I intend to change turns completely zeros.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
>>> s=numpy.array([[1,0,0],[1,0,0]])
>>> s[1]=numpy.array([.3,.3,.3])
>>> s
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly convert to float:

```
s = numpy.array([[1,0,0],[1,0,0]])
s = s.astype(numpy.float32, copy=False)
s[1] = numpy.array([.3,.3,.3])
```

Updated `s`:

```
array([[1. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0.3, 0.3, 0.3]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to dtype in numpy,
Here to understand some executions,

```
In [1]: s = numpy.array([[1,0,0],[1,0,0]])

In [2]: a = numpy.array([.3,.3,.3])

In [3]: s.dtype
Out[3]: dtype('int64')

In [4]: a.dtype
Out[4]: dtype('float64')

In [5]: a.astype(int)
Out[5]: array([0, 0, 0])
```

So, while doing `s[1] = numpy.array([.3,.3,.3])` it's convert to `float64` to `int64` that why it's store as `[0, 0, 0]`

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to keep floats in the future, you may let Python know that by supplying at least one explicit float when creating the object `s`:

```py
s=numpy.array([[1,0,0],[1,0,0.0]])
```